# Minimum temp and maximum temp display using SQL script

Tags: sql, max, minimum

I have a table in which minimum and maximum temperature is stored per order no and date. I want to pick the minimum temperature and maximum temperature for each day. This should be done using SQL script.

Comment: The question lacks research or trial from the askers side.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `group by` clause, and aggregate functions `min`, `max` as below:

```
select date, min(temperature), max(temperature)
from table
group by date
```

It will work if your `date` have only year, month and day (01/11/2012).

Answer (score 0):

In oracle:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_VAL,'DD-MM-YYYY'), MAX(temperature), 
MIN(temperature) FROM table_name group by TO_CHAR(DATE_VAL,'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

In MySQl:

```
   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_VAL, '%d-%m-%Y'), max(temperature), 
   min(temperature) from table_name group by DATE_FORMAT(DATE_VAL, '%d-%m-%Y');
```